# QtService could not start

Tags: c++, qt, service

I have a problem with `QtService` class. I am trying to to build a **Windows service**. I downloaded the [files](https://github.com/qtproject/qt-solutions/tree/master/qtservice) and included them into my project.

Now, when I run the project (in QtCreator) I get message

> The service MyService could not start.

The method `start()` is not executed.

I've found upper message in file **qtservice.cpp** at the end of `QtServiceBase::exec()` implementation.

Do you have any idea why I get this message?

**myservice.h**:

```
#ifndef MYSERVICE_H
#define MYSERVICE_H

#include <QtService/qtservice.h>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QObject>

class MyService : public QtService<QCoreApplication>
{
public:
    MyService(int argc, char **argv);
    ~MyService();
    void start();
    void pause();
    void resume();
    void stop();

private:

};

#endif // MYSERVICE_H
```

**myservice.cpp**:

```
#include "myservice.h"

MyService::MyService(int argc, char **argv) : QtService<QCoreApplication>(argc, argv, "MyService")
{
    qDebug() << "CONSTRUCTOR";
    setServiceDescription("This is my service. ");
    setServiceFlags(QtServiceBase::CanBeSuspended);
    qDebug() << "CONSTRUCTOR 1";

}

MyService::~MyService()
{
    qDebug() << "DECONSTRUCTOR";
    try {

    } catch (...) {
        qCritical() << "An unknown error occured in deconstructor";
    }
}

void MyService::start()
{
    qDebug() << "START";
    try {
        QCoreApplication *app = application();
        qDebug() << "Service started";
        qDebug() << app->applicationDirPath();
    } catch (...) {
        qCritical() << "An unknown error occured in start";
    }
}

void MyService::pause()
{
    qDebug() << "PAUSE";
    try {

        qDebug() << "Service paused";
    } catch (...) {
        qCritical() << "An unknown error occured in pause";
    }
}

void MyService::resume()
{
    qDebug() << "RESUME";
    try {

        qDebug() << "Service resumed";
    } catch (...) {
        qCritical() << "An unknown error occured in resume";
    }
}

void MyService::stop()
{
    qDebug() << "STOP";
    try {

        qDebug() << "Service stopped";
    } catch (...) {
        qCritical() << "An unknown error occured in stop";
    }
}
```

**main.cpp**:

```
#include "myservice.h"
#include <QCoreApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    MyService service(argc, argv);
    return service.exec();
}
```

and **`.pro` file**:

```
QT       += core gui network

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = ServiceTest
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        myservice.cpp

HEADERS  += myservice.h

include(QtService/qtservice.pri)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you passed the argument `-exec` to the service? (click on "Project", then "Run Setting" then fill the Argument field).

The service wants to run as a service unless you pass the `-exec` parameter that tells it to run as an application (so you can debug it).

Other command line parameters are `-install`, `-uninstall`, `-pause`, etc. After you install the service with `-install` then you can run it using the Windows Administrative tools.